# Are the other worlds shown in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. episodes "Repairs" and "Laws of Nature" the same?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In "Repairs" Season 1, Episode 9
Gemma sees this world (at about 19-20 mins)

[image: "Hell"?]

In "Laws of Nature" Season 3, Episode 1,
It is revealed that she has travelled to an alien world.

Is there any clear in-universe or outside-universe evidence that they are either the same or different worlds ?

MCU only please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Probably not.

While the worlds do look similar, and both are referred to as Hell, it's unlikely they're the same place.

When the accident is recreated in "Repairs," the world is brightly lit.

[image: Hell?]

However, Maveth only has a sunrise for a short amount of time every 18 years.

> Will: Even if we do miss it, there'll be another one in 18 years.

Since the sun last rose over 13 years before the episode in question, the timing wouldn't work out.

Secondly, the world shown in "Repairs" is described as a different universe, while [Maveth](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Maveth) is a distant planet in our universe.

> Simmons: This "ghost" is a man trapped between our universe and another.

Additionally, I can find no Word of God linking them.

Comment: No evidence as to what the S1 world/dimension could be then? :(

Comment: @stormie Unfortunately, no.

Comment: It would be the "hell" dimension that Ghost Rider is from? There might be a shot of that through one of the portals in Season 4.